I am trying to create a colour map with plplot using the data from a text file but I keep getting an exception error
I created a program that reads data from a file and creates colour map but when i run the program i get an "Exception has occured. Segmentation fault".
Example of a colour map:

Here I include most of the libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <plplot/plstream.h>
#include <plplot/plplot.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define NSIZE    101

This is a 2d vector function where most of the data is being read and stored.
// Function to read data from a text file
std::vector<std::vector<int> > readData(const std::string& filename) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > data;
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str());
    std::string line;

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::vector<int> row;
        int value;
        while (iss >> value) {
            row.push_back(value);
        }
        if(!row.empty())
        {
            data.push_back(row);
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return data;
}

Here is where I create the colour map using the data from the text file
void createColourMap(const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& data)
{

    int rows = data.size();
    int col = data[0].size();
    plstream *pls = new plstream();

    pls->sdev("xwin");
    pls->init();

    pls->env(0.0, rows, 0.0, col, 1, -1);

    pls->lab("X", "Y", "Colour Map Example");

    PLFLT **z = new PLFLT*[col];
    for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i) {
        z[i] = new PLFLT[rows];
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; ++j) {
            z[i][j] = data[i][j];
        }
    }
    pls->scmap1l(true, 256, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    PLFLT xmin = 0.0, xmax = static_cast<PLFLT>(rows - 1);
    PLFLT ymin = 0.0, ymax = static_cast<PLFLT>(col - 1);
    PLFLT zmin = **std::min(z, z + (rows * col));
    PLFLT zmax = **std::max(z, z + (rows * col));


    pls->col0(1);
    pls->imagefr(z, rows, col, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

Here is my main where I call the functions
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > data;
    data = readData("Test.txt");

    createColourMap(data);

    Here is where the error pops up
    return 0;
}



OT: Leaving a space in nested template invocations hasn't been necessary for a looooong time.

int col = data[0].size(); your code assumes all lines in the file have the same number of entries. If thats not the case or when there is an issue with reading form the file, you will go outof bounds of the vector. Do not store size seperate from the vector. Its one reason to use std::vector that you do not need that.

**std::min(z, z + (rows * col)) is complete nonsense. You are computing an address that is way out of bounds for z (which only has col elements), then you're using min to compare two addresses, which has no relation to the values in z

for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i) {  for (int j = 0; j < rows; ++j) { ... should be for (const auto& row : data) { for (const auto& element : row) ...

@Botje and your suggestion would be....

Use std::min_element on every row vector and combine the results pairwise with std::min. Or calculate the min and max while you're copying data into z.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai why should it be like that?

@Botje that's literally what I am doing. I am calculating the mix and max. is it not?

std::min compares two objects, not a range. Furthermore, you are comparing addresses, not actual values. Your zmin value will effectively always be **z or z[0][0]

you should use a range based for loop when you can because it is much less error prone. Suppose you have a bug in reading from the file. With your loop this means you have 2 bugs, reading the file and the loop. With the range based for loop, the loop will be just fine.
